# How to fix the size of column in table, so the long text can be on next line?

Tags: tables

[image]

```
\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{table*}[t]
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0.1\tabcolsep}
\caption{Comparison with other state of art detection tools} 
\label{tab:example}
\small
\centering
\begin{tabular}{lcccccc}
\toprule\toprule
\textbf{Detection Techniques} & \textbf{Algorithm} & \textbf{Detection 
Time} & \textbf{RAM 
Usage} & \textbf{CPU usage} & \textbf{Database Creation time} \\ 
\midrule\midrule 
\\   
NAYATDROID & DRG-122 & Item 3 & Item 4 & Item 4  & Item 4\\ \\
DroidSG & FNV Hash & Item 3 & Item 4 & Item 4  & Item 4\\ \\
PTVDT& GHU Hash, FNV hash, Nim hash  & Item 3 & Item 4 & Item 4  & Item 
4\\ \\
BGHFT& FVB Hash  & Item 3 & Item 4 & Item 4  & Item 4\\ \\
VFFG & CDC Hash, FNV hash & Item 3 & Item 4 & Item 4  & Item 4\\ \\
VBGFD & GBR Hash  & Item 3 & Item 4 & Item 4  & Item 4\\
\bottomrule \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table*}
\end{multicols}enter code here
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Could you please post a complete compilable code? We don't even know your document class.

Comment: Thank you @Bernard. it is \documentclass[twoside]{article} and the template is \begin{multicols}{2}

Comment: please always post a complete document so people do not have to guess how to make a working example. for example you have not said how \toprule is defined

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible solution with the `makecell` package, which allows for line breaks in cells of standard columns, and a common formatting of column heads:

```
    \documentclass[twoside]{article}
    \usepackage{multicol, booktabs}
    \usepackage{makecell}
    \renewcommand{\theadfont}{\small\bfseries}
    \setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}

    \begin{document}

    \begin{multicols}{2}
      \begin{table*}[t]
    \caption{Comparison with other state of art detection tools}
    \label{tab:example}
    \small
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{lcccccc}
    \toprule\toprule
    \thead{Detection\\ Techniques} & \textbf{Algorithm} & \thead{Detection\\ Time} & \thead{RAM \\%
    Usage} & \thead{CPU\\ usage} & \thead{Database\\ Creation time} \\
    \midrule\midrule
    \\
    NAYATDROID & DRG-122 & Item 3 & Item 4 & Item 4 & Item 4\\ \\
    DroidSG & FNV Hash & Item 3 & Item 4 & Item 4 & Item 4\\ \\
    PTVDT& \makecell{GHU Hash,\\ FNV hash,\\ Nim hash} & Item 3 & Item 4 & Item 4 & Item 4\\ \\
    BGHFT& FVB Hash & Item 3 & Item 4 & Item 4 & Item 4\\ \\
    VFFG & \makecell{CDC Hash,\\ FNV hash} & Item 3 & Item 4 & Item 4 & Item 4\\ \\
    VBGFD & GBR Hash & Item 3 & Item 4 & Item 4 & Item 4\\
    \bottomrule \bottomrule
    \end{tabular}
    \end{table*}
    \end{multicols}

    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. I have multiple tables in the document. makecell package is not working in the documents. it gives errors {(C:\Users\Yasir\AppData\Local\Programs\MiKTeX\tex/latex/makecell\makecell.sty

! LaTeX Error: Command \thead already defined.
               Or name \end... illegal, see p.192 of the manual.}

Comment: Can we fix the column size within table?

Comment: Yes, or course. You can use a `p{some length}` specifier or the `tabularx` environment, for which you set the overall width and use at least one `X`  column. As to the errors you mention in your first comment, it's strange ; I suggest you post a short complete code reproducing the problem.